# How to make a Windows Server 2008 Virtual machine available to a Vista Virtual machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-workstation

I am running Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista on VMWare Workstation 6.5 for the purpose of learning Server 2008 R2. What I desire is a way to network the two virtual machines so the Vista virtual machine can log into the domain on the Windows 2008 Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want these virtual machines to be separate from the rest of your real physical network, simply go to the `Virtual Machine Settings` and choose the `Network Adapter`.

Select `Custom` and choose a network which is not being used by any other device. This will create a private, virtual only network for your machines to communicate via.

[image]